# Read data from all sheets in workbook

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Need to read data from all available sheets in single workbook. 
I'm using the below code,but it is returning the value of only last work sheet.

```
Workbook finalWB =ReadInpuFile.readxl(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//","TestCases.xlsx","TestSuite");

    for(int k=0;k<finalWB.getNumberOfSheets();k++)
    {
      Sheet finalsheet = finalWB.getSheetAt(k);

      if(finalsheet !=null)
      {
        //int rowCount = finalsheet.getLastRowNum()-finalsheet.getFirstRowNum();
        int rowCount = finalsheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println("rowcount" +rowCount);
        object = new Object[rowCount][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) 
        {
          //Loop over all the rows
          Row row = finalsheet.getRow(i+1);
          //Create a loop to print cell values in a row
          for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) 
          {
            //Print excel data in console
            object[i][j] = row.getCell(j).toString();

          }
       } 
    }
}
```

I have 3 sheets in single workbook.
please help me.

Thanks,
Sathya

Comment: I don't see where you are returning anything. Can you post all of your code for the method?

Comment: Hi again, I'm returning Object here.

Answer (score 0):

Use getSheet(index) instead of getSheetAt(index)

Sheet finalsheet = finalWB.getSheet(k);

Answer (score 0):

Below is full method,returning object here

```
public Object[][] getTestCase() throws IOException{
    Object[][] object = null;
 Workbook finalWB =ReadInpuFile.readxl(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//","TestCases.xlsx","TestSuite");

for(int k=0;k<finalWB.getNumberOfSheets();k++){
Sheet finalsheet = finalWB.getSheetAt(k);

    if(finalsheet !=null){
    //int rowCount = finalsheet.getLastRowNum()-finalsheet.getFirstRowNum();
    int rowCount = finalsheet.getLastRowNum();
    System.out.println("rowcount" +rowCount);
    object = new Object[rowCount][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

        Row row = finalsheet.getRow(i+1);
       for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            object[i][j] = row.getCell(j).toString();
            System.out.println(object[i][j]);
        }
    } 
}}
   System.out.println("done");
     return object;    
    }
}
```

Comment: When you're looping through the number of sheets in this method method you're constantly overwriting the values in the `object` array. That's why you're just seeing the results from the last iteration / last sheet.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment: When you're looping through the number of sheets in this method you're constantly overwriting the values in the object array. That's why you're just seeing the results from the last iteration / last sheet.

If you must return a 2D array of Object from your method then you should review this part of your method:

```
object = new Object[rowCount][5];
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

   Row row = finalsheet.getRow(i+1);
   for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
        object[i][j] = row.getCell(j).toString();
        System.out.println(object[i][j]);
    }
}
```